# Is this lemon tree still living

Tags: trees

[image]

The lemon tree branches are dry but the leaves are still green what can I do to save it

Comment: Seems fine to me. In my experience lemon trees are very hearty trees and can undergo a lot of mistreatment without skipping a beat.

Answer (score 1):

It looks alive to me. I have a tree in Denver, so it's in a container and I have to move it in and out of the house for winter/summer. Periodically that process (or forgetfulness about watering) will cause problems and it gets shocked a bit, but as long as there are happy leaves on it then it's in a basically alive shape.

Can you tell us a bit more about where it's planted? What soil is it in? How long as it been there? Has anything changed recently?